# Ignore whole class if subclass contains unwanted value with jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I do this in my Activity:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(https://greselius.net/idesk/vplan/Anzeige/Schueler_heute/subst_001.htm).get(
                );
                Elements questions = doc.select("table.mon_list");
                Elements td = questions.select("td.list:not(.inline_header)");
```

The website it connects to is a substitute teacher plan.
This gets me all elements that contain data of the affected school class, lesson, teacher, etc.
But it gets that for all school classes and I want to get only the elements for one specific school class.
Lets say I want only the ones that contain 9c, how can I ignore the other ones?

```
<tr class="list odd">
<td class="list" align="center">9c</td><td class="list" align="center">5</td><td class="list" align="center">LÜB</td><td class="list" align="center">Ph</td><td class="list" align="center">Ph1</td><td class="list" align="center">LÜB</td><td class="list" align="center">Raum-Vtr.</td><td class="list" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: 9c is a value. I dont think Jsoup filter based on node value. You'll have to iterate and find.

Comment: Re-reading the question after posting my answer, I'm a bit confused as to whether you're referring to a class at your school or a `class` attribute on an element.  Consider clarifying for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the desired scope of the search, you want one of the `:contains()`, `:containsOwn()`, `:matches()` and `:matchesOwn()` [selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

To select only table cells in table rows containing `9c`, you'd use `tr:contains(9c) td`; note that while the selector is applied to `tr`, the child elements are also searched.  If you instead used `td:contains(9c)`, you'd only get the single cell, not its siblings in the row (though you could iterate on the returned elements' siblings, of course).

try.jsoup.org can't fetch the URL you provided due to a certificate error, so I can't give you the exact query you need, but that should get you started.